# Count the number of occurrences of characters in a string?

Tags: python, algorithm

**Given a string** "**a1a3b5a2c4b1**".
The characters are followed by numbers representing the number of occurrences of the character in the string. The correct **solution would return "a6b6c4"** (a1 + a3 + a2 = a6, b5 + b1 = b6, c4)

My original idea was to convert the string into a list, then to a dict of key value pairs.

```
data="a1a3b5a2c4b1"
lst = list(data)
{lst[i]: lst[i +1] for i in range(0, len(lst), 2)}
```

Returns:

```
{'a': '2', 'b': '1', 'c': '4'}
```

The issue is that it does not increase the number of occurrences (values) but takes the last seen value.

How can I create a dictionary that increases the values rather than replaces them?

Comment: Could there be double-digit occurrence numbers?

Comment: very good question! there is no such scenario! only single digit!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You keep overriding the key with the latest count in that comprehension. You would have to rather update them by addition:

```
data = "a1a3b5a2c4b1"

counts = {}
i = iter(data)
for char, count in zip(i, i):
    counts[char] = counts.get(char, 0) + int(count)

# {'a': 6, 'b': 6, 'c': 4}
```

The other natural util to handle counts is, well, a [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

counts = Counter()

i = iter(data)
for char, count in zip(i, i):
    counts.update(**{char: int(count)})
```

This also uses the "[`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) the same iterator" trick to produce chunks of 2. AS for turning these dictionaries into the desired string output:

```
"".join(f"{k}{v}" for k, v in counts.items())
```

Answer (score 0):

If the string is based on sequences of pairs where the first character is your key and the second character is a single digit then:

```
mystring = 'a1a3b5a2c4b1'
mydict = dict()
for i in range(0, len(mystring), 2):
    pair = mystring[i:i+2]
    key = pair[0]
    value = int(pair[1:])
    if key in mydict:
        mydict[key] += value
    else:
        mydict[key] = value
print(mydict)
```

You could play around with defaultdict and/or dictionary comprehension but I think this is clearer